# logging to single file from multiple process using queue,wsgi,rotatingfilehandler is not logging any message to logfiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

There is a scenario where, when log file reaches maxbytes it must create a new log but logging to single file from multiple process using `rotatingfilehandler` is not going fine so I have used queue along with `rotatingfilehandler`

There is a problem, it is not logging the messages to logfiles and the codes is as follows

**Code:**

```
import dash

from flask_caching import Cache

import logging.config

import logging

import logging.handlers as handlers

from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

import queue
import logging
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener


config={

    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s'
    }},
    'handlers':{
        "fileHandler": {
        "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
        "formatter": 'default',
        "filename": "testinglog.log",
        "maxBytes": 1024000,
        "backupCount": 5
    },
    'wsgi':{
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'loggers':{
    "xyz": {
        "handlers": ['wsgi',"fileHandler"],
        "level": "INFO",
        'propagate': True,
    },
}}

log_queue = queue.Queue(-1)

queue_handler = QueueHandler(log_queue)

logger = logging.getLogger()

logging.config.dictConfig(config)

loger = logging.getLogger('xyz')


loger.addHandler(queue_handler)

listener = QueueListener(log_queue, 'wsgi', 'fileHandler')

listener.start()
```

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to format code that's why some code is appearing as text

Comment: I have formatted your question in the good way.

Comment: Can anyone help with this